# How to undo reopen vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, undo

I have just asked a question, which was quickly marked as duplicate. First I got angry, because "duplicate" question didn't contain an answer to my specific scenario and voted for the question to be reopened. Then, however, I looked closer and realized that question is indeed a duplicate. How do I undo my reopen vote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close and reopen votes expire after 4 days. There is no way to undo them.

Comment: Then the next question is WHY???

Comment: @VladLazarenko [meta-tag:status-bydesign]